# Why are the spirits in Deadbeat injured?

Tags: ghost, deadbeat

In the show *Deadbeat*, why do the ghosts of the dead still have their mortal wounds? Isn't an injury specific to the flesh, and not so much the spirit? Was this ever explained on the show?

[image]

Comment: I've never seen the show, and know nothing about it.. BUT, it's a not uncommon [trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OurGhostsAreDifferent) (**WARNING**: That's a TvTropes link with a few examples; following it may lose you large chunks of your day...) to have the dead show the injuries that killed them or are part of their self image.  It pops up in everything from Beetlejuice to The Sixth Sense, and the Dresden files to Odd Thomas, although sometimes not seen until a character looks for it / realizes something.